# Why does my for loop run more times than I specify?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I expect this to give me back 9 keys from the stats dictionary, but instead I get 27. Why does this happen and how do I achieve the result I was trying to get?

```
import random

def statsGen():
    "Will generate an npc's stats"

    level = 3    
    const = random.randint(1, 20)
    str = random.randint(1, 20)
    dext = random.randint(1, 20)
    perc = random.randint(1, 20)
    intel = random.randint(1, 20)
    will = random.randint(1, 20)
    char = random.randint(1, 20)
    sp = random.randint(1, 20)
    luck = random.randint(1, 20)

    stats = {'Const':const,'Str':str,'Dext':dext,'Perc':perc,'Int':intel,'Will':will,'Char':char,'Sp':sp,'Luck':luck}

    for level in stats:
        stat1 = random.choice(list(stats))
        print(stat1)
        stat2 = random.choice(list(stats))
        print(stat2)
        stat3 = random.choice(list(stats))
        print(stat3)


statsGen()
```

Comment: You have 3 Print statements in the for loop and 3 * 9 = 27

Comment: I assume by "give me back" you mean "print"? Why do you expect it to print 9 stats? `for level in stats` will loop 9 times, and in each iteration you have 3 prints. 9*3==27.

Comment: If you want to loop with one iteration per level, use `for l in range(0, level):`

Comment: Yes by "give me back" I mean print, sorry for being new.I did not understand why it was giving me 27 because I believed the for loop would be run three times and print three times per loop. I did not realize it was taking the amount of times to loop from the number of keys in the stats dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the loop controlled by `level`, not `stats`:

```
for _ in range(level):
    name, value = random.choice(stats.items())
    print("{} = {}".format(name, value))
```

However, there is no guarantee with this that you will get three *different* stats, as each call to `random.choice` is independent. Instead, use `random.sample`:

```
for name, value in random.sample(stats.items(), level):
    print("{} = {}".format(name, value))
```

Comment: Thank you. I was planning on using an if statement to test if the key was different or not from the previous ones in the loop, I did not know of random.sample. I appreciate your help and I'm sorry if my question was a nuisance

Answer (score 1):

For every iteration you print 3 stats (stat1, stat2, stat3). 
So, If you iterate over stats dictionairy (9 loops) it gives you 27 printed stats.